# Change tags <strong> in bold and <em> in italic on ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

I want to change the tags

```
<strong> to <font style = "font-weight: bold;">
```

and change the tags

```
<em> to <font style = "font-style: italic;">
```

I've tried it as described in http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.coreStyles_bold

but there is absolutely no change.

Last I turn it into:

```
CKEDITOR.config.coreStyles_bold = { element: 'strong', styles: { font-weight: 'bold' }, overrides: 'b' };
```

expect the result to be:

```
<strong style="font-weight: bold;"></strong>
```

version of CKEditor, 4.1.1

Comment: How did you try it? Please show us your custom configuration and the way you replace the editor. I'm guessing that this might be an ACF issue or a configuration issue. What version of CKEditor?

Comment: I've updated the description of the question.

Comment: Why do you need `font` tag that has been deprecated since 1999? Are you using CKEditor to compose HTML email messages?

Comment: I use it to adjust the settings used web-design in page article. My question, is there a way that I ask? I am using CKEditor to post an article.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want this, this might do the trick:

```
config.allowedContent = true;
config.coreStyles_bold = {
    element: 'font',
    attributes: { 'style': 'font-weight: bold;' },
    overrides: 'strong'
};
```

Set these in the config.js file - not inline. BTW, you are using the wrong documentation, see: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-coreStyles_bold